# Is JNI function SetStringUTFRegion non-existent?

Tags: string, java-native-interface

I see a function named SetStringUTFRegion introduced in the main JNI guide document but can't find it.
Is this function non-existent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You saw it where? I don't see it anywhere in the [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html). I'd be astonished if it existed anywhere. Java Strings are supposed to be immutable after all.

Comment: Footnote: it is indeed mentioned in the Sun Java Series JNI book by Shen Liang (1999), page 30, but it is impossible to believe in its actual existence.

Comment: i saw it in sun JNI book. and I know the strings are immutable and such a method should not exist. just wanted to confirm. Now i believe it does not exist to :)

Comment: @Taheri yeah, it seems like an editorial mistake to me, someone adding it for symmetry not realizing it didn't exist on purpose.